# how to find last word in a string sqlite3

Tags: string, sqlite, substring, string-length

I have values (varchar) with strings. There is a word: John, which repeates within each value at least couple of times.

e.g.

John went to town. He visited his girlfriend. She likes John very much. **John** is in love.

or.

He went to town. John likes football. **John** likes icecream.

Now I need dynamic solution to find position of last written 'John' within string.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, with a recursive CTE. Do you really need to do this in SQL?

Comment: Yes, it's no other way. I have read everything on instr, substr etc., it would be very easy to get first john, however last is complicated.

Comment: Show some example data and the desired result.

Comment: Is the comparison case sensitive?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to [create a custom function](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html) which you can call from within the select statement.